Connection Refused Between SSR Next.js and Laravel API
I'm working in a project where the stack is Laravel API, NextJs, docker and Nginx for reverse proxy and all is redirected to HTTPS.
The communications between frontend and laravel api is working, but I'm having a problem with SSR in NextJs (with axios) when I want to get data from Laravel API .
Issue:
errors: [
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:443
         at createConnectionError (node:net:1647:14)
         at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1677:16)
         at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
       errno: -111,
       code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
       syscall: 'connect',
       address: '::1',
       port: 443
     },
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
         at createConnectionError (node:net:1647:14)
         at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1677:16)
         at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
       errno: -111,
       code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
       syscall: 'connect',
       address: '127.0.0.1',
       port: 443
     }
   ],

Headers and extra data that axios sends
config: {
     transitional: {
       silentJSONParsing: true,
       forcedJSONParsing: true,
       clarifyTimeoutError: false
     },
     adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 0,
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     maxBodyLength: -1,
     env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Cookie: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZsQUdVUXoyYjVLUmc2T1B1TE1ZS3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWGJlUDZmMS9PVzdBWThRRUpPbTdqRWdmbnFxbEVzVjRmSXBBRlpSY3dodytSaEhlMWNpYTFNMHhmQkpLZHZCell4c3ZGVkl4WWZKNWNjeU8vRkk1VGhsMVZIcWpVenUrWGhIMUlOb0ZXeC9HM1p3VlZLaUVjcCs0RkorNml5c00iLCJtYWMiOiIzZWU1ZDI2ZTcyOGNmYmQwNDdlY2ZjZGM3NjU3ODYwY2MyYTE1Nzc1MGYxZDVkNGQ4NGQ1YjczMDI1MDBhZDFkIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=; final_draw_session=eyJpdiI6IllESEtrcEdHVjg1OXZ1c01XcG8vNGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZnNrVEMrRUZ1MjJmK0o4T3BFWWdsNUg2bUVOTHN3R1lvNGowQVFLVkhIRnJpS1A2OUd6c3pQUG1vVTlnSVFoRDlyYStaa1BjUm1XWW0wNGhURFRRMzJLTVFJNCt5T0Zjcjlab2wwZWFseC9vU2MyTmxrMkVEOHdRTGM5cUtZN1QiLCJtYWMiOiI0YTRlY2I2ZDFiOWJiYTIwOTU5ODdhMzUxMmQzNjAxZWVmY2M3ZWEwYTI4OTYxMWRmYWNhNTllNjg4ODBlYThmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=;',
       Origin: 'https://localhost',
       'App-Language': 'es',
       'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.4',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
     },
     baseURL: 'https://localhost/api',
     withCredentials: true,
     method: 'get',
     url: '/categories',
     data: undefined
   },

Nginx config:
upstream backend {
  server findra-php:9000;
}

upstream frontend {
  server findra-node:3000;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen  [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    # SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    if (!-d $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    ## Handle Horizon requests
    location /findra-queues/horizon {
      root /var/www/finaldraw/nadal/public;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

      # PHP-FPM configuration
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass backend;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
      fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }


    ## Handle API requests and pass them to index.php if the file doesn't exist
    location /api/ {
      root /var/www/finaldraw/nadal/public;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin localhost;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    ## Handle PHP requests
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
      root /var/www/finaldraw/nadal/public;
      # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
      fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

      include fastcgi_params;

      fastcgi_pass backend;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }

    ## Handle all other requests with the frontend (Node.js)
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
       deny  all;
    }
}

Docker compose
services:

  # ############################## 
  # ###### SETUP AND BASE SERVICES
  # ##############################

  ## Node builder
  findra-node-builder:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/node
    container_name: findra-node-builder
    restart: no
    user: node
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./federer
        target: ${FRONTEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    working_dir: ${FRONTEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    profiles:
      - builder

  ## Laravel builder
  findra-laravel-builder:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/php
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-0}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-0}
    user: www-data:www-data
    container_name: findra-laravel-builder
    restart: no
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./nadal
        target: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    working_dir: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    environment:
      APP_DIRECTORY: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    depends_on:
      findra-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
      findra-redis:
        condition: service_healthy
      findra-minio:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend
    profiles:
      - builder

  # ########################
  # ###### FRONTEND SERVICES
  # ########################

  ## Node container for regular execution of the Federer project
  findra-node:
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/node
    container_name: findra-node
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./federer
        target: ${FRONTEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    working_dir: ${FRONTEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    command: ["npm", "run", "dev"]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "localhost:3000"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 150
    networks:
      - frontend

  # #######################
  # ###### BACKEND SERVICES
  # #######################

  ## Nginx container
  findra-nginx:
    container_name: findra-nginx
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      findra-php:
        condition: service_healthy
      findra-node:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        published: ${NGINX_PORT}
        target: 80
      - protocol: tcp
        published: ${NGINX_SSL_PORT}
        target: 443
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/certs
        target: /etc/nginx/ssl
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-k", "-f", "https://localhost:443"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 150
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  ## PHP container for regular execution (contains and runs the Laravel base
  findra-php:
    container_name: findra-php
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/php
      args:
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-0}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-0}  
    user: www-data:www-data
    depends_on:
      findra-mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
      findra-redis:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./nadal
        target: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    working_dir: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "php-fpm-healthcheck"]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 150
    networks:
      - backend

  # #########################
  # ###### DATABASES SERVICES
  # #########################

  ## MySQL database
  findra-mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: findra-mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: findra_mysql
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        published: ${MYSQL_PORT}
        target: 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "-u root", "-p ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - backend

  ## Redis database for caching
  findra-redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine
    container_name: findra-redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: findra_redis
        target: /data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - backend

  # ########################
  # ###### MAIL SERVICE
  # ########################

  ## Mailhog service
  findra-mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: findra-mailhog
    restart: unless-stopped
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - protocol: tcp
        published: ${MAILHOG_PORT}
        target: 8025
    depends_on:
      findra-nginx:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend

  ########################
  ###### STORAGE SERVICE
  ########################

  ## Minio storage service
  findra-minio:
    container_name: findra-minio
    image: minio/minio
    command: server --certs-dir /root/.minio/certs --console-address ":${FORWARD_MINIO_CONSOLE_PORT:-9002}" --address ":${FORWARD_MINIO_PORT:-9001}" /data 
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_MINIO_PORT:-9001}:9001'
      - '${FORWARD_MINIO_API_PORT:-9002}:9002'
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MINIO_SERVER_URL: "https://localhost:9001"
    healthcheck:
      test: timeout 5s bash -c ':> /dev/tcp/localhost/9001' || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: findra_minio
        target: /data
      - type: bind
        source: ./config/certs
        target: /root/.minio/certs
    networks:
      - backend

  ##########################
  ####### WORKERS SERVICE
  ##########################

  ## Horizon worker
  findra-horizon:
    container_name: findra-horizon
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/php
    command: ["php", "${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}/artisan", "horizon"]
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./nadal
        target: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    depends_on:
      findra-php:
        condition: service_healthy
    working_dir: ${BACKEND_CONTAINER_PATH}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
  frontend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  findra_mysql: {}
  findra_redis: {}
  findra_minio: {}

Axios config - NextJs
import axios from 'axios'
import { getCookie } from '@/utils/cookies/cookies'
import { DEFAULT_LOCALE } from '@/langs/locales'
import { APP_LANGUAGE } from '@/utils/cookies/constants'

function isServer () {
  return typeof window === 'undefined'
}

const httpAPIClient = createHttpClient('https://localhost/api')

httpAPIClient.interceptors.request.use(setAppLanguageHeader)

function createHttpClient (baseURL) {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}

function setAppLanguageHeader (config) {
  if (config && config.headers) {
    if (!isServer()) {
      config.headers[APP_LANGUAGE] = getCookie('NEXT_LOCALE') ?? DEFAULT_LOCALE
    }
  }

  return config
}

export { httpAPIClient }

Server file where I add the X-XSRF-TOKEN and cookie session.
import { httpAPIClient } from '@/config/httpClient'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { APP_LANGUAGE, FINAL_DRAW_SESSION, NEXT_LOCALE, XSRF_TOKEN } from '@/utils/cookies/constants'

function setAuthServerCookies () {
  const lang = cookies().get(NEXT_LOCALE)
  const xsrfCookie = cookies().get(XSRF_TOKEN)
  const fdsCookie = cookies().get(FINAL_DRAW_SESSION)

  if (xsrfCookie && fdsCookie) {
    httpAPIClient.defaults.headers.Cookie = `X-XSRF-TOKEN=${xsrfCookie?.value}; ${fdsCookie?.name}=${fdsCookie?.value};`
    httpAPIClient.defaults.headers.Origin = `${process.env.ORIGIN}`
    httpAPIClient.defaults.headers.Origin = `${process.env.ORIGIN}`
  }

  httpAPIClient.defaults.headers[APP_LANGUAGE] = `${lang.value}`
}

export { setAuthServerCookies }

Finally my page in Next:
import CategoryService from '@/services/CategoryService'
import { CategoryView } from '@/views/admin/category'
import { setAuthServerCookies } from '@/utils/server'

async function getCategories () {
  setAuthServerCookies()

  try {
    const response = await CategoryService.getAll()
    return response.data.categories
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Category page: ', err)
  }
}

export default async function CateogoriesPage () {
  const categories = await getCategories()

  return (
    <CategoryView categories={categories} />
  )
}

Full Error:
2024-09-13 23:40:18 Category page:  AxiosError [AggregateError]
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at AxiosError.from (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:94:14)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:650:75)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at eventHandlers.<computed> (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:38:24)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:103:11)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:506:5)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:170:8)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:90:21)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at Axios.request (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:57:41)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at async CategoryService.getAll (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/services/CategoryService.ts:9:16)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at async getCategories (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/[locale]/admin/categories/page.tsx:17:26)
2024-09-13 23:40:18     at async CateogoriesPage (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/[locale]/admin/categories/page.tsx:24:24) {
2024-09-13 23:40:18   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2024-09-13 23:40:18   errors: [
2024-09-13 23:40:18     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:443
2024-09-13 23:40:18         at createConnectionError (node:net:1647:14)
2024-09-13 23:40:18         at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1677:16)
2024-09-13 23:40:18         at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       errno: -111,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       syscall: 'connect',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       address: '::1',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       port: 443
2024-09-13 23:40:18     },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443
2024-09-13 23:40:18         at createConnectionError (node:net:1647:14)
2024-09-13 23:40:18         at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1677:16)
2024-09-13 23:40:18         at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       errno: -111,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       syscall: 'connect',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       address: '127.0.0.1',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       port: 443
2024-09-13 23:40:18     }
2024-09-13 23:40:18   ],
2024-09-13 23:40:18   config: {
2024-09-13 23:40:18     transitional: {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       silentJSONParsing: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       forcedJSONParsing: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       clarifyTimeoutError: false
2024-09-13 23:40:18     },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http', 'fetch' ],
2024-09-13 23:40:18     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
2024-09-13 23:40:18     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
2024-09-13 23:40:18     timeout: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
2024-09-13 23:40:18     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
2024-09-13 23:40:18     maxContentLength: -1,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     maxBodyLength: -1,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
2024-09-13 23:40:18     headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       Accept: 'application/json',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       Cookie: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZsQUdVUXoyYjVLUmc2T1B1TE1ZS3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWGJlUDZmMS9PVzdBWThRRUpPbTdqRWdmbnFxbEVzVjRmSXBBRlpSY3dodytSaEhlMWNpYTFNMHhmQkpLZHZCell4c3ZGVkl4WWZKNWNjeU8vRkk1VGhsMVZIcWpVenUrWGhIMUlOb0ZXeC9HM1p3VlZLaUVjcCs0RkorNml5c00iLCJtYWMiOiIzZWU1ZDI2ZTcyOGNmYmQwNDdlY2ZjZGM3NjU3ODYwY2MyYTE1Nzc1MGYxZDVkNGQ4NGQ1YjczMDI1MDBhZDFkIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=; final_draw_session=eyJpdiI6IllESEtrcEdHVjg1OXZ1c01XcG8vNGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZnNrVEMrRUZ1MjJmK0o4T3BFWWdsNUg2bUVOTHN3R1lvNGowQVFLVkhIRnJpS1A2OUd6c3pQUG1vVTlnSVFoRDlyYStaa1BjUm1XWW0wNGhURFRRMzJLTVFJNCt5T0Zjcjlab2wwZWFseC9vU2MyTmxrMkVEOHdRTGM5cUtZN1QiLCJtYWMiOiI0YTRlY2I2ZDFiOWJiYTIwOTU5ODdhMzUxMmQzNjAxZWVmY2M3ZWEwYTI4OTYxMWRmYWNhNTllNjg4ODBlYThmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=;',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       Origin: 'https://localhost',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       'App-Language': 'es',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       'User-Agent': 'axios/1.7.4',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
2024-09-13 23:40:18     },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     baseURL: 'https://localhost/api',
2024-09-13 23:40:18     withCredentials: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     method: 'get',
2024-09-13 23:40:18     url: '/categories',
2024-09-13 23:40:18     data: undefined
2024-09-13 23:40:18   },
2024-09-13 23:40:18   request: <ref *1> Writable {
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _events: {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       close: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       error: [Function: handleRequestError],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       prefinish: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       finish: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       drain: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       response: [Function: handleResponse],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       socket: [Function: handleRequestSocket]
2024-09-13 23:40:18     },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _writableState: WritableState {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       highWaterMark: 65536,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       length: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       corked: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       writelen: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       bufferedIndex: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       pendingcb: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kState)]: 17580812,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kBufferedValue)]: null
2024-09-13 23:40:18     },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _maxListeners: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _options: {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       maxRedirects: 21,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       maxBodyLength: Infinity,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       protocol: 'https:',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       path: '/api/categories',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       method: 'GET',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       headers: [Object: null prototype],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       agents: [Object],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       auth: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       family: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       beforeRedirect: [Function: dispatchBeforeRedirect],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       beforeRedirects: [Object],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       hostname: 'localhost',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       port: '',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       agent: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       nativeProtocols: [Object],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       pathname: '/api/categories'
2024-09-13 23:40:18     },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _ended: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _ending: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _redirectCount: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _redirects: [],
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _requestBodyLength: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _requestBodyBuffers: [],
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _eventsCount: 3,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _events: [Object: null prototype],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _eventsCount: 7,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _maxListeners: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       outputData: [],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       outputSize: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       writable: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       destroyed: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _last: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       chunkedEncoding: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       shouldKeepAlive: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _defaultKeepAlive: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       sendDate: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _removedConnection: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _removedContLen: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _removedTE: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       strictContentLength: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _contentLength: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _hasBody: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _trailer: '',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       finished: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _headerSent: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _closed: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _header: 'GET /api/categories HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'Accept: application/json\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'Cookie: X-XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZsQUdVUXoyYjVLUmc2T1B1TE1ZS3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWGJlUDZmMS9PVzdBWThRRUpPbTdqRWdmbnFxbEVzVjRmSXBBRlpSY3dodytSaEhlMWNpYTFNMHhmQkpLZHZCell4c3ZGVkl4WWZKNWNjeU8vRkk1VGhsMVZIcWpVenUrWGhIMUlOb0ZXeC9HM1p3VlZLaUVjcCs0RkorNml5c00iLCJtYWMiOiIzZWU1ZDI2ZTcyOGNmYmQwNDdlY2ZjZGM3NjU3ODYwY2MyYTE1Nzc1MGYxZDVkNGQ4NGQ1YjczMDI1MDBhZDFkIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=; final_draw_session=eyJpdiI6IllESEtrcEdHVjg1OXZ1c01XcG8vNGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZnNrVEMrRUZ1MjJmK0o4T3BFWWdsNUg2bUVOTHN3R1lvNGowQVFLVkhIRnJpS1A2OUd6c3pQUG1vVTlnSVFoRDlyYStaa1BjUm1XWW0wNGhURFRRMzJLTVFJNCt5T0Zjcjlab2wwZWFseC9vU2MyTmxrMkVEOHdRTGM5cUtZN1QiLCJtYWMiOiI0YTRlY2I2ZDFiOWJiYTIwOTU5ODdhMzUxMmQzNjAxZWVmY2M3ZWEwYTI4OTYxMWRmYWNhNTllNjg4ODBlYThmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=;\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'Origin: https://localhost\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'App-Language: es\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'User-Agent: axios/1.7.4\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'Host: localhost\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
2024-09-13 23:40:18         '\r\n',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       agent: [Agent],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       socketPath: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       method: 'GET',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       maxHeaderSize: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       path: '/api/categories',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _ended: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       res: null,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       aborted: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       upgradeOrConnect: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       parser: null,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       maxHeadersCount: null,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       reusedSocket: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       host: 'localhost',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       protocol: 'https:',
2024-09-13 23:40:18       _redirectable: [Circular *1],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kChunkedBuffer)]: [],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kChunkedLength)]: 0,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kSocket)]: [TLSSocket],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(errored)]: null,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 65536,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
2024-09-13 23:40:18       [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
2024-09-13 23:40:18     },
2024-09-13 23:40:18     _currentUrl: 'https://localhost/api/categories',
2024-09-13 23:40:18     [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
2024-09-13 23:40:18     [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
2024-09-13 23:40:18   },
2024-09-13 23:40:18   cause: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]: 
2024-09-13 23:40:18       at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1117:18)
2024-09-13 23:40:18       at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1684:7)
2024-09-13 23:40:18       at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
2024-09-13 23:40:18     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2024-09-13 23:40:18     [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
2024-09-13 23:40:18   }
2024-09-13 23:40:18 }


It seems you're trying to connect to localhost, for a container, it'd mean itself, not your host machine.
Try connecting to https://servicename, in your case, https://findra-nginx

I tried with findra-php:9000 but you right, now the message changed to cause: Error: unable to verify the first certificate. It's not working but I understand with your answer
